# Indexing in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

For an internship this Summer, I have found myself using Excel VBA on a regular basis. I've had to self teach to get by, so I am not especially proficient and have ran into an issue with my latest assignment.

I basically have a report where in Sheet1 column B I have a series of ID numbers varying in length. These numbers correspond to a name. I would like my macro to read the number and give me the corresponding name on Sheet2 in the same cell, but my problem is I have about 200,000 rows of values. I have to imagine using loops is wildly inefficient if not impossible because of how long it would take to run.

Is there a faster, more efficient way to do this?

Comment: In general, the problem seems doable with a simple `INDEX(MATCH)` or `VLOOKUP`. Not in general, show what you have done so far to help further.

Comment: Where is the ID<>Name relationship stored?

Comment: I ended up adopting VLOOKUP into my code in VBA and it worked well. Thanks for the suggestion. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use built-in function. It seems like "HLOOKUP" will work for you.